# how to put IDispatch* in managed code

Tags: c#, automation, com-interop

I've been considering trying to write a COM object using C# that implements a OPOS Service Object. I've done it in C++ using Automation and MFC and it wasn't too difficult. So I'm stuck on one of the methods trying to convert it over. I'll exclude the other methods in the interface since they are straight forward (or so I hope).

```
[id(6), helpstring("method OpenService")]
LONG OpenService(BSTR lpclDevClass, BSTR lpclDevName, IDispatch* lpDispatch);
```

My C# code looks something like this so far, but i'm stuck on OpenService.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("76F8309C-3837-4065-960F-BE156383896D")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch)]
public class IErtMSR
{
    [DispId(1)]
    int COFreezeEvents([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VariantBool)] bool Freeze);
    [DispId(2)]
    int GetPropertyNumber([In] int lPropIndex);
    [DispId(3)]
    void SetPropertyNumber([In] int lPropIndex, [In] int nNewValue);
    [DispId(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    string GetPropertyString([In] int lPropIndex);
    [DispId(5)]
    void SetPropertyString([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string StringData);
    [DispId(6)]
    int OpenService([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string lpclDevClass, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string lpclDevName, IDispatch* lpDispatch);
    //...the rest of the 24 methods.
}
```

as you can see I don't know what to put for IDispatch*. What do I use in this case?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to create a IDispatch method (which I found that Hans Persant had that available..) Now I just gotta figure out how to invoke a event from it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a managed definition for COM `IDispatch` or implement its members explicitly. The Framework has a built-in support for it. Just declare your `OpenService` like this:

```
[DispId(6)]
int OpenService(
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string lpclDevClass, 
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string lpclDevName, 
    [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch] object lpDispatch);
```

Comment: In my head I see this as working just fine, but the signature says IDispatch*. Shouldn't I make it `ref object lpDispatch`?

Comment: @RobertSnyder, no, `ref object` would mean it's possible to return an `IDispatch` object from the call. That would map to `[in, out] IDispatch** p` in IDL. Just make sure the `object` you're passing implements a `IDispatch`-compatible interface, e.g.: `[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual] interface ITest { /*... */ }`. You can also use `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDispatch/AutoDual)]` on the object's `class`, but I'd stick with a separate interface like `ITest` and `[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITest))]` on the class.